# Filter list with another list

Tags: c#

I have two lists and I need to check if another list has the same content. If there is similar content, I need to save to a variable those ones.
How do I compare if a list content contains another ones content?

For example:
listA has (a, b, c, d, f) and listB has (c, f, h, j)
the return value must be (c, f)

Comment: What is a,b,c,d,f? What have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

There is an elegant solution in LINQ (requires `using System.Linq` at the top of the file):

```
var itemsInBoth = listA.Intersect(listB);
```

Comment: Nice, I'll try that one! Just a question, both of the lists must have the same model/type?

Comment: @Araújo yes, the signature is `Intersect<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TSource>)` where `TSource` is "The type of the elements of the input sequences." so all types must match. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=netframework-4.8. You could use `ConvertAll` to convert one list to the other's type if necessary.